# How to fetch all unique values of a field in a single elastic-search aggregation bucket?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, download

I have a huge number of documents on elastic search, which have lots of status fields from various systems.
I want to apply the filtering on the es index first to get the ids of the records and then download those from mysql.

i.e. i want to fetch all the values of a field say cid, as an array in es response.

If i just ask for a _source ["cid"], that still gives individual documents and is too slow (i want to fetch ~1M records).
Another option is to use terms aggregation, that is faster but still gives individual buckets for each id.

Is there a workaround where i can fetch those many ids of the documents (using aggregation/script/query)?

Currently I am doing :

```
{
 "size": 0, 
 "query":{
   "bool": {
     "filter": {
       "term": {
         "source": "web"
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "aggs": {
   "ids": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "cid",
       "size": 10000
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Any solution or advice would be helpful.

Comment: agg is the way. What if your problem with the buckets ? It s should be easy in java to map bucket to array. When you say "slow" what do you mean? Do you need all the cid at the same time or you can start to work with the first you receive (like a pagination)?

Comment: I need all at once (possibly millions of documents)